# JOIN Same table with different results

Tags: sql, postgresql

'messages' Table:

[image]

I need to pick a user id, say, '23' and have the following data:

`Conversations Initiated by 23`: 2

`Rejections received by those conversations`: 1

`Response Rate Percentage`: 50%

This is what I began writing, but been banging my head ever since.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT from_specific_user.id) AS "Conversations initiated",
       count(DISTINCT from_users.id) AS "Response Rate"
FROM message as from_specific_user
JOIN message AS from_users
    ON from_users.recipient_id = from_specific_user.sender_id
    AND from_users.initial_conversation = FALSE
    AND from_users.from_id = from_specific_user.to_id
WHERE from_specific_user.from_id = '23'
AND from_specific_user.initial_conversation = TRUE
```

As I understand it, I need to `select all messages where from_id = '23' and initial_conversation = true`. Then I need to query all messages again to find all the messages sent from the receiving end of the result above.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation.  You can do this for all `from_id`s at once:

```
select from_id,
       count(*) as messages_initiated,
       count(*) filter (where rejection) as num_rejected,
       avg( rejection::int ) as ratio_rejected,
from messages m
group by from_id;
```

Adding a filter for a single `from_id` is trivial.

Comment: Where do I insert the `from_id = 23` in your example?

Comment: Add `where from_id = 23`.